# Import products via command line using Magento\ImportExport\Model\ImportFactory in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, import, csv, importexport, product-import

I want to import products from `.csv` file using command line. Referring to this link: `https://www.thirdandgrove.com/insights/importing-products-magento2-part2/` everything is working fine, except situation where i have some mistake in my `.csv` file. For example if my custom attribute has wrong value the script will not import products. Importing products from **admin panel** will skip wrong products and all correct will be imported. I tried to change the `'validation_strategy'` but it did not help. Where is mistake in this script? What should i change? 
I will be very grateful for any advices.